# Postgres how to sort specific condition in 1 to many condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

student_table:

```
 id  |  name   
------+--------
 1002 | Vidya    
 1007 | Danielle 
 1010 | Linda    
 1011 | Nick    
 1013 | Lisa     
 1016 | YinYue   
 1018 | Arif     
 1019 | John
```

score_table:

```
student_id   |  course_name | score
-------------+---------------+
 1002        | math          |  90
 1002        | english       |80
 1002        | physics       |88
 1013        | japanese      |90
 1013        | english       |88
 1013        | art           |87
 1016        | math           |87
 1010        | math           |91
 1007        | art           |88
```

not all the students have the same course

how can I select all the students by the order of math score, students who don't take math just stay at the bottom

the result of example shoud be:

```
 id  |  name   
------+--------    
 1010 | Linda 
 1002 | Vidya        
 1016 | YinYue
 1013 | Lisa
 1007 | Danielle   
 1018 | Arif     
 1019 | John
```

The original idea is to select all the math score in order and then match the select all the students, pair student_id with students and fill the rest who dont have math records

```
select * from score_table where course_name = 'math' order by score Desc;

select * from students_table
```

but it will be hard to set the limit and skip

Comment: You want a LEFT JOIN. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two tables using an outer join, then you can sort by the score and sort the null values (for students without a course) at the end.

```
select st.id, st.name, 
       sc.score
from student_table st
  left join score_table sc 
         on st.id = sc.student_id 
        and sc.course_name = 'math'
order by sc.score nulls last;
```

It's important to put the condition on `course_name` into the join condition, otherwise the outer join is turned back into an inner join.